# Arcs - data modeling

Tags: sql, data-modeling

I am reading [this](https://sqldatabasetutorials.com/sql-db/arcs/) post about arcs from data modeling.

This example says:

> Arcs are a way to represent mutually exclusive relationships in the
> ERD.
> This arc represents the exclusive OR relationship – each
> MEMBERSHIP must be held by one COMPANY or must be held by one
> CUSTOMER, but not both.

[image]

My doubt is: how do I implement this physically in database? Do I need to create I trigger or something else to validate one or other, but not both at the same time? or if is there some constraint to use in this case?

Comment: Please only tag specific RDBMS if you want a solution specific to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do below things:

- Create Table : MembershipType

  - Id
  - MembershipTypeName
- Add Two columns to Membership table

  - MembershipTypeId
  - MemberId

You need to make sure that MembershipTypeId, MemberId combination is unique, so that you can identify whether the membership is being held by Customer or Company.

Comment: Now I understood, not necessarily I need 3 tables in the datavase like the entities on DER model. Very clear, thanks.